# Multi core ZeroMQ?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, zeromq

ZeroMQ is used for receiving input parameters..

```
def server():
    rep = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    rep.bind('tcp://*:{}'.format(PORT))

    while True:
        data = rep.recv_json()
        result = calculate(data)
        rep.send_json(result)
```

The calculation method is called `calculate`, after finished, `result` would be sent to client through ZMQ.

Base on my test, it currently uses only 1 core of the machine, now I wanted to use other cores. I've read some docs about `multiprocessing` and `multithreading`, but they mainly focus on fixed inputs, which is not my case.

So I need some kindly help now..

Comment: I tried `Multithreaded Hello World server` in the [official guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:all), but it only uses single core..

Comment: Do you want `calculate` itself to use multiple cores, or do you want to be able to run `calculate` on multiple inputs concurrently? Doing the former might be difficult depending on the details of `calculate`, doing the latter should be pretty simple.

Comment: @dano both .. How simple can it be? (I might take care of `calculate` itself later)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can use `multiprocessing` to have multiple worker processes that can deal with concurrent clients connecting:

```
import zmq
from multiprocessing import Process

def calculate(data):
    return {"output": data['ok']}

def handle_request(url):
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    socket.connect(url)
    while True:
        data = socket.recv_json()
        print("received {}".format(data))
        out = calculate(data)
        socket.send_json(out)

def server():
    context = zmq.Context()
    # Set up socket for clients to connect to.
    clients = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
    clients.bind('tcp://*:{}'.format(5556))

    # Set up ipc socket for workers to connect to
    url_worker = 'ipc:///tmp/workers'
    workers = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
    workers.bind(url_worker)

    # Start 4 worker processes    
    for _ in range(4):
        p = Process(target=handle_request, args=(url_worker,))
        p.start()

    # Forward requests from clients to the workers via a Queue
    zmq.device(zmq.QUEUE, clients, workers)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server()
```

Now, if you point a sample client at it:

```
import zmq
from threading import Thread

def send_req(request):
    context = zmq.Context()

    print("Connecting to hello world server...")
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5556")
    print("Sending request %s ..." % request)

    socket.send_json({"ok" : "Hello"})

    message = socket.recv()
    print("Received reply %s [ %s ]" % (request, message))

#  Do 10 requests in parallel
for request in range(10):
    Thread(target=send_req, args=(request,)).start()
```

You get the following output:

```
Connecting to hello world server...
Sending request 0 ...
Connecting to hello world server...
Sending request 1 ...
Connecting to hello world server...
Sending request 2 ...
Connecting to hello world server...
Sending request 3 ...
Connecting to hello world server...
Sending request 4 ...
Connecting to hello world server...
Sending request 5 ...
Connecting to hello world server...
Sending request 6 ...
Connecting to hello world server...
Sending request 7 ...
Connecting to hello world server...
Sending request 8 ...
Connecting to hello world server...
Sending request 9 ...
<5 second delay>
Received reply 0 [ {"output":"Hello"} ]
Received reply 1 [ {"output":"Hello"} ]
 Received reply 3 [ {"output":"Hello"} ]
Received reply 2 [ {"output":"Hello"} ]
<5 second delay>
Received reply 4 [ {"output":"Hello"} ]
Received reply 5 [ {"output":"Hello"} ]
 Received reply 6 [ {"output":"Hello"} ]
Received reply 7 [ {"output":"Hello"} ]
< 5 second delay>
Received reply 8 [ {"output":"Hello"} ]
Received reply 9 [ {"output":"Hello"} ]
```

Comment: It's important to note that @dano does NOT use a socket concurrently, but he instead forward the messages to multiples backend sockets. This is because ZeroMQ sockets are not thread safe.

Comment: Thank you! I'm wondering what does `4` mean? Tried multiprocessing.cpu_count(), it returns 4, seems like CPU thread count...  Python process will make use of one core or one thread?

Comment: @SnoopyGuo I just picked 4 arbitrarily. `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` would be a good choice if `calculate` is CPU-bound (which it probably is, based on the name). Each process will be single-threaded, but they can scale across CPU cores. So if you've got 4 cores, 4 processes can each use one of the cores in parallel.